# Integration using residues $\int z^2 \log [(z+1)/(z-1)] dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$\int z^2 \log [(z+1)/(z-1)] dz$ taken around circle $|z|=2$

I am taking residues at $\pm 1$.

This gives me 0 as the value of integral. Is this correct.

How do I modify the integral to get value over half the circle?

Comment: The residue at $z=\pm 1$ does not make sense. You should take the residue at infinity.

Comment: I need to take residues at poles right and those poles which lie inside the |z|=2

Comment: Yes. $\pm1$ are not poles, they are *branch points*.

Comment: But Cauchy residue theorem requires that poles be inside |z|=2, which as I see it there are no such poles. Then we can't apply residue theorem can we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_C f(z)dz=-2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)$$
But we have $$f(z)=2z+\frac23z^{-1}+o(z^{-1})$$ as $z\to\infty$, 
therefore the integral equals $\frac43 \pi i$.
$f$ is not meromorphic in $|z|<2$ , so we can not apply residue theorem inside the circle, but we can apply it outside the circle.

Comment: But Cauchy residue theorem requires that poles be inside |z|=2, which as I see it there are no such poles. Then we can't apply residue theorem can we?

Comment: @Piyush Cauchy residue theorem requires *meromorphicity*. The function is not even meromorphic in that circle.